# Add html tag in Custom Label and use in LWC Component not working

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

I have used bold tag for bold text in the custom label and used that custom label in my lightning web component but in my component text is not printing bold.

Custom Label Name: `KM_HelloWorld`

Value: `Hello < b >World.< /b >`

---

### helloworld.html

```
<template>
    {label.HelloWorld}
</template>
```

---

### helloworld.js

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

import helloworld from '@salesforce/label/c.KM_HelloWorld';

export default class helloworld extends LightningElement {

    label = {
        KMAppointmentBooked
    };
}
```

---

Output: `Hello < b >World.< /b >`

Answer (score 6):

Use lightning formatted rich text.

```
<lightning-formatted-rich-text
    value={label.HelloWorld}
></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
```